# grep with multiple patterns supplied in a file

Tags: regex, file, grep

I have a couple of patterns I would like to ask grep to find in some files.
Assume I have a file containing

```
pattern1
pattern2
pattern3
pattern4
...
patternx
```

and instead of editing a grep in front of each pattern,like:

```
grep pattern1 arg
grep pattern2 arg
...
grep patternx arg
```

I would prefer to feed the whole amount of patterns one time to grep and have grep produce the output.

I could iterate in a sh for loop of course but the question whether it is possible using grep one time is what I'm asking myself here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you are looking for this:

```
grep -f yourPatFile /path/files
```

You can read man page of grep to find out the details of `-f` option, basically it allows grep to use patterns in a file(each line as pattern)

Comment: Ouch. So easy. Thanks.